# Count Distinct is not working in UDF in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I am facing problem in creating UDF with `count distinct` in query. I have created a table **amtest** which have the following :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[amtest](
    [ztime] [datetime] NULL,
    [zutime] [datetime] NULL,
    [zid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [xamacadyr] [int] NOT NULL,
    [xamreg] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [xmobile] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [xamclasssec] [varchar](30) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [zid] ASC,
    [xamacadyr] ASC,
    [xamreg] ASC
)
```

Data in the **amtest** table are as follows:

```
zid xamacadyr   xamreg      xmobile         xamclasssec
100000  2013        201508001   01713236075     Section-B
100000  2014        201508003   01713236072     Section-A
100000  2015        201508001   01713236071     Section-A
100000  2015        201508003   01713236073     Section-A
100000  2015        201508004   01713236074     Section-A
```

Now I have created an User-defined-functions with parameter `xamreg` so that, for any xamreg value, there can not be 2 distinct value in xamclasssec field. For example, here for **201508001** value in xamreg, there should not be 2 distinct values (Section-A, Section-B), it should only allow either **Section-A** or **Section-B**. For that I have created the following UDF:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckTest](@xamreg varchar(30))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @retvar int;
    select @retvar = COUNT(*) from (select xamclasssec from amtest where xamreg=@xamreg group by xamclasssec) as tbl ;
    RETURN @retvar
END
```

And I have created a constraint for `amtest` table, which is as follows:

```
alter table amtest  
add constraint chkAmtest  
check(dbo.CheckTest(xamreg)<=1)
```

Where I have made a mistake, as it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your function can be simplified to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckTest](@xamreg varchar(30))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT xamclasssec) FROM amtest WHERE xamreg = @xamreg);
END
GO
```

I run your query with SQL Fiddle it seems to work but only with `INSERT`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ec42/2/0)**

If I try to set `DISTINCT` values you get:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chkAmtest".
>   The conflict occurred in database "db_3_5ec42", table "dbo.amtest",
>   column 'xamreg'.

But there is one drawback with your solution, it won't work when `UPDATE` occurs.

**[SqlFiddleDemo2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39335/1/0)**

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[amtest]
        (zid ,xamacadyr  , xamreg ,     xmobile  ,       xamclasssec)
VALUES (100000 , 2013  ,      201508001 ,  01713236075 ,    'Section-B'),
       (100000,  2015,        201508001 ,  01713236071 ,    'Section-B');

UPDATE [dbo].[amtest]
SET xamclasssec =  'Section-A'
WHERE xmobile = 01713236071;

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[amtest];
```

Use **`AFTER TRIGGER`** instead:

**[SqlFiddleDemo3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b362/3/0)**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_amtest 
ON [dbo].[amtest]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
  IF EXISTS (SELECT xamreg, COUNT(DISTINCT xamclasssec)
             FROM amtest
             GROUP BY xamreg
             HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT xamclasssec) > 1)
  ROLLBACK;
GO
```

Comment: Yah,boss,this UDF is working with insert query fine but when i **update** any record,it is not working,i didn't check with trigger(your alternate solution). But is it not possible with UDF for checking during updating records?

Comment: As I said your UDF will check data, but before UPDATE is done. So no, with UDF it is impossible. AFTER TRIGGER is correct way